# Why is my pressure reduction valve screeching?

Tags: plumbing

I have a screeching sound coming from my plumbing. It seems to be from the pressure reducing valve when I turn on almost any faucet in the house. It started to happen when I turned off the water to an outside faucet. The noise stops when I turn on the water to the outside faucet.

I live in Canton, Ga in a 30 year old house with copper pipes. I had a gas water heater and pressure reducing valve replaced in July in 2023.

Everything worked fine until I turned the water off to an outside faucet. With the outside faucet turned off and the water to the faucet turned on there is no screeching sound. When the  water to the faucet is turned off and the outside faucet is off there is a screeching sound when I flush the toilet and use any sink faucets in the house.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Also. What did you do just before this started happening? Air trapped in pipes that have been drained but not flushed/refilled can produce some terrifying resonances. (I posted a question and answer about that; in my case it was the feed to the dishwasher that hadn't been refilled and running the start of a cycle cured the problem.)

Comment: Great point, @keshlam. Between July & Dec it's _likely_ the OP would have used water from every outlet in the house, but there may be that one guest bath that hasn't had the shower run or the toilet flushed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/217437/low-foghorn-noise-after-new-pressure-reduction-valve-and-expansion-tank-installe